# Specify location of a textbox in a Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am looking for a smart way to make sure that the textbox I am including in my plot is in the top right or top left corner. Just like the legend for example. Even if you rescale your plot it sticks to the original location. The command for that is 'Location', 'NorthWest' for example. But that doesnt work for textboxes. Maybe someone has an intelligent solution.

Thanks

Comment: what's a `textbox` in your case? a `uicontrol` or an annotation created via the `text` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using normalized units for the `'position'` property of the textbox. To do that, set the `'units'` property to `'normalized'`. You then choose the `'position'` values between `0` and `1`.

The problem is that the `'position'` property defines not only position, but also size. So in addition to  the textbox remaining in the desired (normalized) position, its size will be rescaled. That may be desired behaviour or not.

```
uicontrol('style','text', 'units','normalized', ...
    'position',[.83 .88 .1 .05], 'string','Hello')
```

You can also set `'FontUnits'` to `'normalized'` and then choose `'FontSize'` in normalized units if you want the text (not just the textbox) to be resized.

Comment: Just as clarification: the four coordinates for `'position'` are `[left bottom width height]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How can I frame the text?

Comment: @user2175762 Sorry, I've never done that. Maybe draw a rectangle manually (with `rectangle`)... but the problem is how to compute its position

Comment: Thanks again. The frame isn't that important. But if I export it as .pdf the text becomes pixelated. Any Ideas about that?